# z-index elements over dynamically generated html

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div that is using fixed positioning with a z-index of 100 which I want to overlap all other elements on the page. I am having some problems with jquery ui tabs and dynamically generated html.

It seems that since the content in the tab is dynamically generated, it gets a higher stack order, so it overlaps my div element. Is there a way to always have the div at the top of the stack order?

I have also tried setting the z-index order of the .ui-tabs class to 0 (didn't work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the HTML is dynamically generated should have no impact on the z-index. I think it's more likely that you're making a mistake with the CSS. Z-index can be a tricky property, but the way to make sure it works correctly is to declare a position: property on every element that could potentially interfere with it. That probably means you just need to declare position:relative, along with z-index:0 on the elements you want to make sure it overlaps.

If you could post the resulting HTML & the CSS affecting it (i.e. after the dynamically generated HTML has been loaded in the page), that might also help.

Comment: was a bug in the plugin i was using

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to write some fancy JS that auto-bumps z-index, but I doubt that is necessary.

More likely there are errors in the HTML and CSS.  **Link to the page in question, or save the source at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/) and link to that.**

In general:

1. Order and tree-level still count; place the super element directly after the `<body>` tag, even though it is positioned separately.
2. A `z-index` of 100, is not enough to guarantee it has the highest value.  I've seen [sites use z-indices of 199999 (EG: div#control)](http://jsbin.com/#javascript,html), or higher!
3. Be careful of `opacity` settings.

See:

- [Understanding how z-index works](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/everything_you_always_wanted_to_know_about_z-index_but_were_afraid_to_ask.asp)
- [z-index demonstration tool](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp)
- [Understanding CSS z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/understanding_css_z-index)

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. It seems when dynamic content creates vertical scrollbars those scrollbars cover a portion of the div. I'm not sure how to fix that. I'm using a browser resize plugin, so when I expand the page ever so slightly the position is fixed to handle the scrollbars.

Comment: Solved. It was an issue with a jquery plugin calulating a left position value, so I changed it to right: 0, and no problems.